# Modal height with online form

Tags: jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-modal

I would know how change the height of my form in my modal, when i define a height in the CSS only the height of the modal "behind" the form change,
Its online form so i cant apply a CSS style on the form

I want do it because the height of the form is too high and it continue after the captcha

[image: like this]

My modal

```
<div class="modal fade" id="contact" data-backdrop="false">
  <div class="modal-dialog modal-lg">
    <!-- Modal content-->
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-body">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
          <div class="pipedriveWebForms" data-pd-webforms="https://pipedrivewebforms.com/form/2067fd4d72477805424c879502205cc81994719"><script src="https://pipedrivewebforms.com/webforms.min.js"></script></div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

My CSS

```
.modal-body {
    padding: 20px 50px;
}

.modal-body {
    position: relative;
    padding: 15px;
}
```

Comment: Life will be easier if you provide a complete code

Comment: I've run the html and css you provided and the modal height is ok. So the problem you show happens in wider context of code that opens the modal. Inspect the modal after opening in browser dev console and find any other CSS that might affect its height.

Answer (score 1):

You're loading an iframe in the modal window. Yoiur document has no information about the height of your iframe (if this one doesn't send this information to your document). But, if you know that the iframe always will have a fixed height: in your example 605px, you can use this in your css:

```
.pipedriveWebForms {
     height: 800px !important; /* you have to update this to fit your needs */
}
```

a fiddle here: https://jsfiddle.net/0jhpzkes/